# Why don't work a tag external link with jquery mobile in phonegap on my mobile device

Tags: cordova

I build phonegap app, a tag external link do work when testing phonegap developer app but i build phonegap on http://www.build.phonegap.com not work a tag external link on my device, Why?, Please

Comment: Please post your config.xml and any Content-Security-Policy meta tag in the head element of your index.html file, also which platform(s) are you targeting please? (iOS, Android, both, others?)

Comment: @Min without code and config.xml, its very difficult to make any guesses

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the domain of the external link in the whitelist of the cordova application?

If the domain is not in the whitelist, it will probably work when you are testing the application using the phonegap app. But once the application is built and installed on a phone, external links to domains that are not whitelisted won't work.

[see this link to learn more about the whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)